# How can I get a list of all of the line numbers of headers / subtrees in an Org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, line-numbers

E.g., with this input:

`* Test
A thing!
** Testing
* Hello`

Get this output:

`(1 3 4)`

Answer (score 3):

`org-map-entries` is a great function for this sort of thing:

> (org-map-entries FUNC &optional MATCH SCOPE &rest SKIP)
>
> Call FUNC at each headline selected by MATCH in SCOPE.

To do what you outlined above ***from within the target file*** it's simply a matter of:

```
(org-map-entries (lambda () (line-number-at-pos)) nil 'file)
```